# Call image from ANY subfolder of 'Uploads'

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Is it possible to ask Wordpress to look in all 'uploads' folder and not just a specific one? As you'll see from the script below, it's looking for images with the same name and a specific prefix...

```
'wp-content/uploads/2012/01/'
```

I want it to be something like...

```
'wp-content/uploads/*/*/'
```

as the way it is, it's not working for anything else, for example if the image file has the prefix...

```
'wp-content/uploads/2012/02/'
```

My script is...

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$(".gigthumb").each(function() {
        var a = $(this).parent();
        a.attr("href", a.prev().attr("href"));
    });



$('img.gigthumb').each(function(){
var foo = $(this).parent().attr('href').split('/').pop();
$(this).attr('src','wp-content/uploads/2012/01/' + foo + '.jpg');
});


$('img.gigthumb').error(function() {
  $(this).attr('src','wp-content/plugins/gigpress/images/placeholder.gif');
});
```

Hope this makes sense. Quite difficult to explain the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing this would be *very* cumbersome and terribly slow. You would have to serve all the possible paths from server side, and then walk through them using Ajax requests or something. It's not a good solution.

The problem should be solvable more easily by changing the way Wordpress organizes your uploads. The setting is in <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Media</kbd>:

[image]

I don't know, however, what happens if you do this on an existing install that already has uploads. You may have to reorganize/re-upload all your posts' content to be able to use this (I'm pretty sure WP won't automatically re-organize.) Use at your own risk and make backups.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for your answer @Pekka. Seems like a good solution but sadly not practical at this stage. Site is now live and there's a lot of media that would need to be reuploaded. Hmmm. This puts me in a bit of a situation now.

Comment: @Kelvin hmm, that stinks. Looking at your code though - I don't comletely understand what it does - isn't the full path of the image known to you at *some* point in the Javascript?

Comment: It's a script created to customise the Gigpress plugin and add thumbnails. Basically, the user uploads an image file that's the same name as the post id in the URL (eg. 'an-example-event') and the script adds it to the events listing. It's active here [link](http://www.londonirishcentre.org/upcoming-events)

Comment: @Kelvin right. Hmm, if the post URL is *not* organized by month and year, this may be difficult - except if you'd want to use the post's internal date to "guess" the upload URL, which might work although it would be very hackish

Comment: I bit the bullet and just deselected the option. Wasn't bad at all. Just kept a copy of the files already categorised, so no need to relink them. Just moved those that will appear on the page, and any new uploads will go to a universal folder. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do the trick.
Post a request to the server (through AJAX). The server returns the path to all files with commas to separate them, once back on the client jQuery splits this string of data at the commas and puts the full paths in an array. When this is done you can simply loop through the array and create an image element for every element of the array, or do whatever you want.

The PHP file

```
<?php
function ListFiles($dir) {

    if($dh = opendir($dir)) {

        $files = Array();
        $inner_files = Array();

        while($file = readdir($dh)) {
            if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') {
                if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $file)) {
                    $inner_files = ListFiles($dir . "/" . $file);
                    if(is_array($inner_files)) $files = array_merge($files, $inner_files); 
                } else {
                    array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file);
                }
            }
        }

        closedir($dh);
        return $files;
    }
}


foreach (ListFiles('wp-content/uploads') as $key=>$file){
    echo $file .",";
}
?>
```

SOURCE: http://tycoontalk.freelancer.com/php-forum/41811-list-files-in-directory-sub-directories.html#post202723

jQuery:

```
  $(function(){
        $.post("getallfiles.php",{/*post data to server if needed*/}, function(data){
          //Splitting with comma expecting it not to be in filenames and directory names.
          var uploads = data.split(','); 
          //uploads[0] would return the first image's path if I'm correct.
        })
  });
```

I think this works, I didn't try it out though, all you need to do is loop through the uploads array and do whatever you want with the imagepath.

Comment: I'm not sure how jQuery's split handles a split when it's character is at the end, I'm guessing it'll just fill this element of the array with null?